# how i set the Observer in magento2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1

this is my code in magento 1

```
class Namespac_Modulename_Model_Observer
{ 
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs) 
    {

        // Get the quote item
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        // Load the custom price
        $price = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);
        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

    protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
    {


        $price;
        $price = $_POST['finalPrice'];
        return $price;
    }

}
```

how i convert this in the magento 2

Comment: Which event you are using in the Magento 1?

Comment: You can check with http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108324/magento2-change-bundle-item-price-in-cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is similar observer for the Magento 2:

> Set Custom Price of Product
>
> First create events.xml file in folder `Webkul/Hello/etc/frontend` and
>   use event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
>     <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
>         <observer name="customprice" instance="Webkul\Hello\Observer\CustomPrice" />
>     </event>
> </config>
> ```
>
> Now create `CustomPrice.php` file in Observer folder.
>
> ```
> <?php
> /**
>  * Webkul Hello CustomPrice Observer
>  *
>  * @category    Webkul
>  * @package     Webkul_Hello
>  * @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
>  *
>  */
> namespace Webkul\Hello\Observer;
>
> use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
>
> class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
> {
>     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
>         $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
>         $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
>         $price = 100; //set your price here
>         $item->setCustomPrice($price);
>         $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
>         $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

[Source](http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/)

Comment: great thanks for reply @Siarhey Uchukhlebau can you tell me please one thing also protected function  protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
    {
  $price;
        $price = $_POST['finalPrice'];
        return $price;
    }
 function  how i use this in the magento 2 in this observer also

Answer (score 2):

Follow [Events And Observer](https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/) guide to make observer and then update this line in **events.xml** with your own event.

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
```

and `execute()` function of Observer class with your above code.Choose your event wisely you can look into [this](https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/) guide for that.